# Bitbucket pipelines workspace variables vs repository variables. Which will be called if both are present?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to develop multiple pipelines in bitbucket and want to understand Which variable will be called if both  workspace variables and repository variables are present with same name?

Under Wroksapce variable I have `FOO=BAR`

Under Repository variable I have `FOO=YES`

So when I call from pipeline `$FOO` what will be the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/#):

> The order of overrides is Deployment > Repository > Workspace > Default variables

So, in this case, repository variables take precedence over workspace variables of the same name, so `FOO` would have the value `YES`.